# How to display relevant data by click the tab

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, jsp, request-mapping

I have a web application that uses Spring MVC and Hibernate. I follow this document https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/navs/#tabs to create tabs.

In jsp the code for the tab is

```
     <div id="memberDiv" class="container">
    <div id="memberAccountManagement" class="jumbotron">
        <h3>Member List</h3>
        <hr class="mb-4">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" id="other-tab"
                data-toggle="tab" href="#other" role="tab" aria-controls="other"
                aria-selected="true">Other</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" id="regular-tab"
                data-toggle="tab" href="#regular" role="tab"
                aria-controls="regular" aria-selected="false">Regular</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
            <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="other" role="tabpanel"
                aria-labelledby="other-tab">Other member content here
                <br />
                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>ID</th>
                                <th>NAME</th>
                                <th>ROLE</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <c:forEach var="member" items="${members}">
                                <tr>                                
                                    <td>${member.id}</td>
                                    <td>${member.username}</td>
                                    <td>${member.memberRole.role}</td>
                                    <td>${member.enabled}</td>                           
                                </tr>
                            </c:forEach>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="regular" role="tabpanel"
                aria-labelledby="regular-tab">Regular member content here
                <br />
                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>ID</th>
                                <th>NAME</th>
                                <th>ROLE</th>
                                <th>ENABLED</th>
                                <th>&nbsp;</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <c:forEach var="member" items="${members}">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>${member.id}</td>
                                    <td>${member.username}</td>
                                    <td>${member.memberRole.role}</td>                              
                                </tr>
                            </c:forEach>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    </div>
        </div>              
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is part of the code in the MemberService.java

```
//for other member
@Override
public List<LoginMember> getOtherAllMember() {
    List<LoginMember> memberAccountManagementList = new ArrayList<LoginMember>();
    memberAccountManagementList = memberDao.list("from LoginMember u where u.memberRole.role='ROLE_Other' order by u.username");
    return memberAccountManagementList;
}

//for regular member
@Override
public List<LoginMember> getRegularAllMember() {
    List<LoginMember> memberAccountManagementList = new ArrayList<LoginMember>();
    memberAccountManagementList = memberDao.list("from LoginMember u where u.memberRole.role='ROLE_Regular' order by u.username");
    return memberAccountManagementList;
}
```

Here is part of the code in the MemberServiceImpl.java

```
public List<LoginMember> getOtherAllMember();
public List<LoginMember> getRegularAllMember();
```

I have the controller(MemberController.java) to call the function for display.

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/memberAccountManagementList"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String memberaccountmanagementlist(ModelMap model) {
    model.addAttribute("members", memberService.getRegularAllMember());
    return "memberAccountManagementList";
}
```

I run the application, When I click the Regular tab, it can retrieve memebers that belong to Regular. However when click the Other tab, it also shows the members belong to Regular.

I think maybe the controller needs to do something. So I duplicate the code in controller and rename it

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/memberAccountManagementList"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String memberaccountmanagementlist(@RequestParam("myTab")  String myTab, ModelMap model) {   
    System.out.println(myTab);  //try to show value
    //model.addAttribute("members", memberService.getRegularAllUser());
    model.addAttribute("members", memberService.getOtherAllMember());
    return "memberAccountManagementList";   
}
```

When I run the application, it occurs an error, it says

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map 'memberController' method
```

I read this post [Spring mvc Ambiguous mapping found. Cannot map controller bean method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29949423/spring-mvc-ambiguous-mapping-found-cannot-map-controller-bean-method) but I don't have the idea how to show relevant member by click the tab.

So my question is how to display relevant data by click the tab? I guess I should write code in the controller but

I should be grateful if someone can give advice on this issue please.

Update:

From this post [@RequestParam vs @PathVariable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13715811/requestparam-vs-pathvariable) , I tried to use `@RequestParam` to get the id `myTab` in the jsp file and pass to the controller.

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/memberAccountManagementList"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String memberaccountmanagementlist(@RequestParam("myTab")  String myTab, ModelMap model) {   
    System.out.println(myTab);  //try to show value
    //model.addAttribute("members", memberService.getRegularAllMember());
    model.addAttribute("members", memberService.getOtherAllMember());
    return "memberAccountManagementList";   
}
```

However when I run the code, I have this error message

```
Message: Required String parameter 'myTab' is not present

Description: The server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing).
```

From the error message, it says `myTab` is not present, but the id  `myTab` exists in the jsp file.

So from the error description, the id `myTab` is not pass to the controller, I don't know which part is not correct.

Would someone let me know my mistake. Grateful for your advice please. Thank you.

I updated the code in controller:

```
    public String memberaccountmanagementlist(@RequestParam(value="#regular", required=false) String regular,ModelMap model) {  
System.out.println("requestparam value is " + regular);
    if (regular== "#regular")
    {

        model.addAttribute("members", memberService.getRegularAllUser());
    }
    else if(regular =="#other")
    {
        model.addAttribute("members", memberService.getOtherAllMember());
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("need to further investigate");
    }
```

When I run the application, it still shows the similar error message and description.

```
Message: Required String parameter '#regular' is not present

Description: The server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing).
```

In `@RequestParam`, I think maybe the `#` will effect the code but no matter I put `#regular` or `regular` or `#other` or `other`, the error message shows the similar thing. I don't understand why it does not work.

Comment: Not so sure about this topic, but if you can get the `id` of each tab in your controller, then you could simply decide on which method to call

Comment: @XtremeBaumer, thank you for your comment. I tried to the pass the `id` in the controller yesterday unsuccessful. I read this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13715811/requestparam-vs-pathvariable, so I used `@RequestParam("myTab")` in the controller. The `myTab` is the id in jsp file. I added the updated in the post, would you mind have a look and grateful for your advice please. Thank you.

Comment: You need to somehow pass in the `li class` ID. I assume you update the website as soon as a list element is selected. So that should be the entry point. As I see it, you already call `href="#regular"` on the list elements. This could also be your way to determine which method to use as you know which `href` has been called

Comment: @XtremeBaumer, thank you for your advice. I notice when I use `@RequestParam`,  no matter I put `#regular` or `regular` or `#other` or `other` (the `a href` value), the error message shows the similar thing. I don't understand why it does not work. Would you please feel free to look at the updated code. Thank you.